# How can i dynamically look-up a XML file in informatica?

Tags: java, xml, informatica-powercenter

I want to look-up a XML file in informatica. I am writing some id in XML file & after writing into XML i want to check weather the record is in XML file or not.

I tried considering XML file as flat file but not able to perform this check dynamically.Can i use Java transformation to check this?

Please help

Thanks